# JavaFX WebView programmatically set zoom

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

Is there a way to programmatically set the zoom on a JavaFX WebView?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

API is available in the upcoming JavaFX 8.

```
webView.setZoom(0.5);
```

You can download early access build of JDK 8 (which includes FX8) here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/ea-jsp-142245.html